# Sum Values in a Nested Dictionary Containing Duplicates

Tags: python, sum, tuples, defaultdict

I've a `defaultdict(int)` of tuples (it contains 2 inner keys) and I'd like to sum the values of **only** those inner keys which have the same 1st element of the tuple.

For example:

```
dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

dict[key][elem_one, elem_two] += 1  # defaultdict format

# The keys (elem1, elem2) and their values (ints) under the first outer key:
(a1, b1) = 1
(a2, b2) = 1
(a2, b1) = 7
(a3, b3) = 4
(a3, b1) = 10
```

I'd like to sum `b1`, `b2`, and `b3` together, regardless of the value of `a` in the first element of the tuple, and output a set containing just the values of `b` with their summed values. Desired output:

```
{b1 = 18, b2 = 1, b3 = 4}
```

What I've tried so far is:

```
out_set = {k[1]: v for k, v in dict[key].items()}  # k[1] gives me b
```

This gives me the correct format, but the wrong numbers! It's not summing. I get something like:

```
{b1 = 1, b2 = 1, b3 = 1}
```

So I tried to change my code as follows:

```
out_set = {k[1]: sum(v) for k, v in dict[key].items()}  # k[1] gives me b
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can I correct this?

In my actual code, my `defaultdict(int)` is much larger. For instance, one key can contain 16 values of `(elem1, elem2)` with their respective values. What I've found is that when I convert to the set, it removes any duplicate `elem2` (which is desired), but it seems to take a random value that's associated with `elem2`, and not the sum of duplicate `elem2`s (which is desired).

Comment: I'm sure is just a typo coming from simplifying the code, but in your example you have two keys `(a1, b1)` (`(a1, b1) = 1` and `(a1, b1) = 7` so the first one will be overwritten by the second) Is just that I'm writing an answer and I was going nuts as to why the sum for `b1` is `17` instead of `18` **:-D**

Comment: @BorrajaX Oh yes, you're right, it's a typo. I'll correct it. Thanks for pointing it out! Regardless, what I'd like to do is sum the values for all elements of `b`, irrespective of what `a` is.

Comment: *what I'd like to do is sum the values for all elements of b, irrespective of what a is*: I wrote an answer with that intention. Doesn't it work? If it doesn't leave a comment and we'll work through it **:-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use another [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and take advantage of the fact that the default value for an integer is `0`, and therefore, you will be able to add to a newly declared (and not explicitly initialized) integer because it's gonna be implicitily initialized to `0` anyway. Something like that:

```
import collections

dct = {
    (1, 1): 1,  # This will be overwritten by (1, 1): 7
    (2, 2): 1,
    (1, 1): 7,
    (3, 3): 4,
    (3, 1): 10
}

aux_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
for key, val in dct.items():
    aux_dict[key[1]] += val
print(aux_dict)
```

Will output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 17, 2: 1, 3: 4})
```

However, because of how tuples (and dicts) work, I find important insisting in the fact that you can not have two keys that are equal. Meaning, this...

```
dct = {
    (1, 1): 1,  # This will be overwritten by (1, 1): 7
    (1, 1): 7,
}
print(dct)
```

... will just output `{(1, 1): 7}`. If you need to keep duplicate keys... somehow, well, that's a different issue: that is not related to summing values, but to how to keep "duplicate" keys in a dictionary. I quote the *duplicate* because you really can't have two keys that are the same. We'll need to figure out a way of not considering those keys as duplicate.

What I mean with the paragraph above is that you won't be getting `b1: 18` because `(a1, b1): 1` is not in the dictionary of values to be added to begin with since you have `(a1, b1): 7` latter in the code.